# Getting Errors after New Project Initialization using gdx-setup-ui.jar

Tags: java, gwt, libgdx

I'm using libgdx-0.9.8
Trying to figure out how to resolve these issues:

- The constructor LwjglApplication(Main, LwjglApplicationConfiguration) is undefined
- The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint. Fix the build path then try building this project
- The type com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced

Resolution:
I installed the GWT Plugin for Eclipse (http://www.gwtproject.org/download.html) and last two errors were resolved.

Comment: post the compleat stacktrace please

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you use Google ADT Bundle (recommended) or as plugin for Eclipse
2. You should install JDK
3. Import all projects in eclipse by selecting import->Existing Project Into Workspace
4. For android errors RIGHT CLICK on "*-android" project and select "properties" then select "Android", and check "Android 4.2.2", also you may check on properties->java build path->order and export-> Android private library
5. For GWT you should go right click on project and select "quick fix", you may check during installation with gdx-setup-ui.jar on lower left part of gdx-setup-ui.jar they suggest 2 fixes
6. And First before you run the program you may BUILD it project->Build All or Ctrl + B

You should name your packages with lower case of characters.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs in my xyz-desktop project.
In gdx-setup-ui, the Game Class value I used was Main.
This was causing the issue.
I named the game class to something else and error ("The constructor LwjglApplication(Main, LwjglApplicationConfiguration) is undefined") no longer existed.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.title = "abc";
    cfg.useGL20 = false;
    cfg.width = 480;
    cfg.height = 320;

    new LwjglApplication(new Main(), cfg);
}
}
```